timed out waiting for node assignment when creating a kafka topic with SSL security applied to a three-node cluster
I am learning kafka on my own and I have come across a problem. I am trying to create a kafka topic with SSL security applied on my brokers (I have a three-node cluster) but I am getting timedout waiting for a node assignment error. I don't have this problem when I create a topic with no security applied to my brokers. can anyone help me with this? any suggestions would be appreciated
the command I run: kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
the result I get: Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
[2024-07-24 13:22:52,137] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
(org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand)
I have tried some modifications in zookeeper.properties and server.properties files but noting seems to work.

You'll need to pass --command-config flag with a property file containing the SSL certificate information

If you mean adding ssl. files (e.g. ssl.truststore.location, ssl.client.auth, and so forth ), I have already put them in server.properties and zookeeper files

Yes, those are server certificates. You'll also need to generate and supply client certificates for cli commands

I appreciate your help. could you explain a little bit more? or if possible, provide a link so that I can read about it.

This guide uses Docker, but shows how to generate various certificate files. https://developer.confluent.io/courses/security/hands-on-setting-up-encryption/
